# node-inspector does not display source code for debugging

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, node-inspector

My node inspector chrome recently does not show the source code for debugging anymore. It has a weirch find/replace dialog, that i'm unable to close it. Have tried reinstalling node-inspector and reinstalling chrome, but it does not fix the issue. I'm able to see some variable values on the right bar but cannot see the whole page of source code [image]